# Selenium:Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated when interacting with dropdown menu

Tags: python, parsing, selenium-webdriver

**EDIT 1**
Solution, proposed by Abhay Chaudhary was temporary only.
After several executions, this is not useful anymore. WebDriverWait returns selector as an empty string and same error appears.

**INITIAL**
An error occurs when I tried to select value (or click button) from dropdown menu.
I`v tried to use both methods: Select and click(), but no luck.
Here is my code:

```
url = 'https://www.arrow.com/en/categories/capacitors/fixed-capacitors/capacitor-ceramic-multilayer?page=1'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
source_data = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML;")
source_data
selector = Select(driver.find_element('css selector', '#SearchResults-perPage'))
selector.select_by_value('100')
```

or:

```
url = 'https://www.arrow.com/en/categories/capacitors/fixed-capacitors/capacitor-ceramic-multilayer?page=1'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
source_data = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML;")
source_data
selector = driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="jumpToProducts"]/div/pagination-bar/div/div/span')
selector.click()
value = '#SearchResults-perPage > option:nth-child(4)'
click()
```

Usage 'click()' method seems to be problematic because selector and value tage are not nested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use code below, Added WebDriverWait to dynamically wait for Dropdown to be preset, then scroll the element into view using javascript and then select value as 50 , i have tested the code and able to select pagination dropdown value, Also updated the locator to be more robust

```
        from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
        from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
        from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
        from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        url = 'https://www.arrow.com/en/categories/capacitors/fixed-capacitors/capacitor-ceramic-multilayer?page=1'
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(5)
        source_data = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML;")
        
        selector = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="jumpToProducts"]/div/pagination-bar//select')))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",selector)
        dpDown=Select(selector)
        dpDown.select_by_value("50")
```

Comment: Same error, unfortunately.  When I try to execute you code separately, another error appears: "Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 106
Current browser version is 112.0.5615.138 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Stacktrace:" 
I have 112 version

Comment: your chromedriver version is not correct that why you are getting above error
go here (https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) and download driver version 112, should solve above issue

Comment: I have 112 version. I`v updated your code by mentioning path to  webdriver version 112 like: 
s = Service(path to webdriver)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(services = s) like in my original code.
After that initial error occured again

Comment: After restarting notebook, deleting several cdc, together with stealth  and direct path to webdriver it works. Thank you!

Comment: After several executions, this is not useful anymore, unfortunately....